# taking the avg in C program

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{


    int n;
    int numbers;
    int i=0;
    int sum=0;
    double average;
    
 

  printf("\nPlease Enter the elements one by one\n");
  while(i<n)
   {
     scanf("%d",&numbers);
     sum = sum +numbers;
     i++;
   }

  average = sum/n;

  printf("\nSum of the %d Numbers = %d",n, sum);
  printf("\nAverage of the %d Numbers = %.2f",n, average);

  return 0;
}
```

i get the output "exited, floating point exception"
im not sure how to fix it.
i found online to add before the while loop

```
  printf("\nPlease Enter How many Number you want?\n");
  scanf("%d",&n);
```

but i dont want that there

Comment: "i dont want that there". Then where do you want `n` to come from? At the moment `n` is never set. It has to be set to some value before using it: `while(i<n)` and `average = sum/n;`

Comment: You never set `n`, and even if you fix that problem, you're still doing integer division, which you clearly don't want (since `average` is declared `double`).

Comment: Without entering the n value before the while you are not giving the limit to the while loop. Or in the other sense you are not telling your program how many numbers to take or when to stop the loop. So you need to take n value before the while loop itself.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: you want the user to be able to signal to your application that they finished entering the elements. So you'd start with `n=0` and then increment it each time the user provides a new element, and exit the loop when the user does "something" that you can detect.

For starters, let's say that the user closes the input by pressing Ctrl-Z on Windows, or Ctrl-D on Unix. The input will fail with EOF then - `scanf()` won't return `1` anymore. So you can check for this:

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int n = 0;
    int sum = 0;

    printf("\nPlease Enter the elements one by one. ");
#ifdef _WIN32
    printf("Press Ctrl-Z to finish.\n");
#else
    printf("Press Ctrl-D to finish.\n");
#endif
    for (;;)
    {
      int number;
      int result = scanf("%d", &number);
      if (result == 1) break;
      sum = sum + number;
      n ++;
    }
    
    double average = (double)sum / n;
    
    printf("\nSum of %d number(s) = %d\n",n, sum);
    printf("Average of %d number(s) = %.2f\n",n, average);
    return 0;
}
```

But this also ends the input when anything non-numeric is entered. Due to how `scanf()` is designed, you need to do something else to skip invalid input - usually by consuming input character-by-character until an end of line is reached. Thus, the variant that would not stop with invalid input, but allow the user another chance, needs to differentiate between `scanf()` returning `EOF` vs it returning `0` (invalid input):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void skip_input_till_next_line(void)
{
    for (;;) {
        char c;
        if (scanf("%c", &c) != 1) break;
        if (c == '\n') break;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int n = 0;
    int sum = 0;

    printf("\nPlease Enter the elements one by one. ");
#ifdef _WIN32
    printf("Press Ctrl-Z to finish.\n");
#else
    printf("Press Ctrl-D to finish.\n");
#endif
    for (;;)
    {
      int number;
      int result = scanf(" %d", &number);
      if (result == EOF) break;
      if (result != 1) {
          // We've got something that is not a number
          fprintf(stderr, "Invalid input. Please try again.\n");
          skip_input_till_next_line();
          continue;
      }
      sum = sum + number;
      n ++;
    }
    
    double average = (double)sum / n;
    
    printf("\nSum of %d number(s) = %d\n",n, sum);
    printf("Average of %d number(s) = %.2f\n",n, average);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a learner I'd recommend you to think about the pseudo code rather than the actual code.

Answers above are really good. I just want to add few things:

As a programmer you've to teach the hardware what you want it to do. Think:

1. Have you told your program how many numbers it takes as input? Is it limited or unlimited?
2. How will your program knows when to stop taking inputs?
3. I hope you agree that `(sum n)/n` would throw an error if user
   doesn't enter anything or only enters `0`?
4. What will happen if User enters characters instead?

***Another important thing is that you need to clearly specify why you don't want to do certain thing in your code? This might help us understand better what are the limitations.***

If you think about these things before and ask questions you'll learn better. Community is here to help you.